# String modification and sampling change

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

i have this table:

| ID | points | values (x1;y1|x2;y2|x3;y3|x4;y4..........) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 0,5;1|1;1,5|4;6|5;7|6;9|8;10|10;12|15;18 |
| 2 | 4 | 20;30|21;32|22;36|25;37 |
| 3 | 306 | 1;2|3;6|7;9|10;17|11;18|13;22|14;25|19;26|.. |

the `points` determine the number of points. It means for example - 306 (306 `x` points and 306 `y` points)

My overall goal is to change the sampling density (the start and end points remain) - when i have 8 points, i want 4 points or when i have 306 points, i want 153 points.

I started like this:

```
df['values']=df['values'].str.replace('|', ';')
df['values'] = df['values'].str.split(';',expand=True)
```

| ID | points | values (x1;y1|x2;y2|x3;y3|x4;y4......) | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 0,5;1|1;1,5|4;6|5;7|6;9|8;10|10;12|15;18 | 0,5 | 1 | 1 | 1,5 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 7 | 6 | 9 | 8 | 10 | 10 | 12 | 15 | 18 |
| .. | ... | .. | ................................... | .. | .. | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |

But I would like, as I wrote above, half as many samples and columns named as follows:

| ID | points | values (x1;y1|x2;y2|x3;y3|x4;y4......) | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 0,5;1|1;1,5|4;6|5;7|6;9|8;10|10;12|15;18 | 0,5 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 15 | 18 |
| .. | ...... | ............................................ | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |

Comment: This does not seem to be the correct approach. in the example above if you accomplish your goal you'll end up with 306 columns on row 3 but these 306 column will mostly be NaN on rows 1 and 2. instead what you should have is x and y columns where rows would represent the index. i.e. first row x1,y1. second row x2,y2

Comment: @Geom Well, I will upload the resulting dataframe to the DB, with this approach I will upload a lot of duplicate rows (except coordinates) to the DB, so I would like to put this in columns. I don't mind that the values will be NaN.

Comment: @Geom But even in the case you mention. How could this sampling be changed?Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems wasteful to create so many new dataframe columns, when many of the cells will be empty, and there is no relation between the values in any given column. More naturally, you could store each sample of points as a list containing pairs, all within one new column of the dataframe.

To obtain the point lists, you can manipulate each `values` string to match the Python syntax and then pass it to `eval()`, if you can trust the data source to contain no malicious code.

The sampling can then be done with Python's slicing syntax, although it's a bit tricky, because you want to include the first and last values.

The above transformations can be defined as a function, so that you can easily apply them to each string in the `values` column:

```py
import pandas as pd
from math import ceil

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                   'points': [8, 4, 306],
                   'values': ['0,5;1|1;1,5|4;6|5;7|6;9|8;10|10;12|15;18',
                              '20;30|21;32|22;36|25;37',
                              '1;2|3;6|7;9|10;17|11;18|13;22|14;25|19;26']})


def list_sample(s):
    """
    Convert string s to a list of value pairs 
    and return the list with every other pair left out
    (but may leave no or double gap in the middle, 
    to always include the last pair).
    """
    pair_string = '[(' + s.replace(',', '.').replace(
        ';', ',').replace('|', '), (') + ')]'
    pair_list = eval(pair_string)
    mid = ceil(len(pair_list) / 2)
    return pair_list[:mid:2] + list(reversed(pair_list[-1:(mid-1):-2]))


df['sample'] = df['values'].apply(list_sample)
df
```

```
  ID points values                                    sample
0 1  8      0,5;1|1;1,5|4;6|5;7|6;9|8;10|10;12|15;18  [(0.5, 1), (4, 6), (8, 10), (15, 18)]
1 2  4      20;30|21;32|22;36|25;37                   [(20, 30), (25, 37)]
2 3  306    1;2|3;6|7;9|10;17|11;18|13;22|14;25|19;26 [(1, 2), (7, 9), (13, 22), (19, 26)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is nice solution. The only problem I have with this is that when I send it to MSSQL DB(`df.to_sql("Process", con=cnx, if_exists="replace", index=False, chunksize=100, method='multi' )` ) - it pops up an error with an unsupported type - `ValueError: found an unsupported type`

Comment: I already solved problem desribed above. I had to do one line code yet : `df['sample'] = df['sample'].where(df['sample'].isnull(), df['sample'].astype(str))`